# Create a sliding anchor links menu

Tags: html

Sorry if this question has already been answered, but I couldn't find the thread.

I created a blog post that is far tooooooooo long (35,000 words), and want to create a better experience for the reader.

I am trying to figure out how to code an anchor links menu that will display within the blog post only and slide up and down the screen with the user so if they feel like jumping back and forth they can without having to scroll up and down the page manually.

Is this possible, and if so can you point me to a page or post that will show me how to code this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I believe the term you are looking for is "infinite scroll".

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether this is what you want.
[An example on W3C School](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links_bookmark)

If you mean, you want to a chapter menu always be a fix place in order to let users click it conveniently. Try this.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
}
.menu{
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
i{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="container">

<div>
<h2 id="C1">Chapter 1</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2 id="C2">Chapter 2</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2 id="C3">Chapter 3</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2 id="C4">Chapter 4</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 5</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 6</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 7</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 8</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 9</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 10</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 11</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 12</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 13</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 14</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 15</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 16</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 17</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <i><a href="#C1">Jump to Chapter 1</a></i>
      <i><a href="#C2">Jump to Chapter 2</a></i>
      <i><a href="#C3">Jump to Chapter 3</a></i>
      <i><a href="#C4">Jump to Chapter 4</a></i>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not really.  On that example where it says "jump to chapter 4"  I want the "jump to chapter 4"  to move scroll down the page as I do.  So for this example when I jump to chapter 4 after I am done reading I don't want to jump back to the top or scroll back to the top I want the "jump to chapter   " jump link right there on the screen above what i am reading so I can jump around chapter to chapter without having to click back to top to click jump to chapter ____  I want all 20 jump to chapter____  jump links to be readily available to a user where ever they are on a page

Comment: I edited the code. Please take a look whether it can help. :)